# Recreate circular diagram with ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm trying to recreate the following illustration with R and `ggplot2`:

[image: The Clean Architecture]

I've created the following piece of code:

```
library(ggplot2)

df <- data.frame(names = c(
  "Enterprise Business Rules",
  "ApplicationBusiness Rules",
  "Interface Adapters",
  "Frameworks & Drivers"))

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = names)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1) +
  coord_polar() +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank())
```

But the output is incorrect:

[image: ggplot2 output]

I can't figure out how to change the order of layers. Maybe I'm missing something really important about `ggplot2` and `data.frame`s.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By default the names are ordered alphabetically. You can get around that by making `names` a factor and specifying the order with the `levels` argument. Separately, you can reverse the names ordering in the legend with the `reverse = TRUE` argument to the `guide_legend` function.

```r
library(ggplot2)

names <- rev(c(
  "Enterprise Business Rules",
  "ApplicationBusiness Rules",
  "Interface Adapters",
  "Frameworks & Drivers"))
df <- data.frame(names = factor(names, levels = names))

ggplot(df, aes(x = factor(1), fill = names)) +
  geom_bar(width = 1) +
  coord_polar() +
  xlab("") + ylab("") +
  theme_void() +
  theme(legend.title = element_blank()) +
  guides(fill = guide_legend(reverse = TRUE))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2019-04-04 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.1)</sup>

Answer (score 2):

Heres a crude solution:

Note the levels of `df$names`

```
> levels(df$names)
 [1] "ApplicationBusiness Rules" "Enterprise Business Rules"        
      "Frameworks & Drivers"      "Interface Adapters"
```

What you need to do is redefine the levels of `df$names`

```
> df$names<-factor(df$names,rev(df$names))
> levels(df$names)
  [1] "Frameworks & Drivers"      "Interface Adapters" 
  "ApplicationBusiness Rules" "Enterprise Business Rules"
```

Now try your graph.